# How do I center a semi-circle doughnut chart?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I'm trying to display a doughnut or semi-circle chart inside a materialize card, which is a responsive div.

I need to display simple data and use the chart as a progress bar. I started from the example in the [HighCharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-semi-circle) documentation.

Now I need to position the plot at the bottom, but remove the white space from the top. If I set the position at center:[50%,50%] there is a white space at the bottom of the container.

Is there a way to crop the height of the container and keeping the aspect ratio?

This is the code I'm using:

```
var data = [  
{  
    name: 'Done',  
    y: 76.1,  
    color: "#ff6666",  
    dataLabels: {  
      enabled: false  
    }  
  },  
  {  
    name: 'To do',  
    y: 23.9,  
    color:"#dddddd",  
    dataLabels: {  
      enabled: false  
    }  
  }  
];  

Highcharts.chart('container', {  
  chart: {  
    plotBorderWidth: 0,  
    height:"400px"  
  },  
  title: {  
    text: 'Title'  
  },  
  tooltip: {  
    pointFormat: '<b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'  
  },  
  plotOptions: {  
    pie: {  
      dataLabels: {  
        enabled: true,distance: -50,  
        style: {fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'white'}  
      },  
      startAngle: -90,  
      endAngle: 90,  
      center: ['50%', '100%']  
    }  
  },  
  series: [{type: 'pie',name: 'Value',innerSize: '70%',data: data}]  
});
```

Here is the result I get:

[image: result]

Comment: I'm not sure how highchart works but you can set `min-height` in css to be the same as width that way you will have square element and you will be able to position it with css.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play around a bit with container height, plotOptions.pie.center and plotOptions.pie.size to get the right dimensions. Please check the code below. I have changed the height of your chart to 200px, center to ['50%', '70%'] and added size of 200%.

See the sample here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pGVyQX?&editable=true

```
var data = [  
{  
    name: 'Done',  
    y: 76.1,  
    color: "#ff6666",  
    dataLabels: {  
      enabled: false  
    }  
  },  
  {  
    name: 'To do',  
    y: 23.9,  
    color:"#dddddd",  
    dataLabels: {  
      enabled: false  
    }  
  }  
];  

Highcharts.chart('container', {  
  chart: {  
    plotBorderWidth: 0,  
    height:"200px"
  },  
  title: {  
    text: 'Title'
  },  
  tooltip: {  
    pointFormat: '<b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'  
  },  
  plotOptions: {  
    pie: {  
      dataLabels: {  
        enabled: true,
        distance: -50,  
        style: {fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'white'}  
      },  
      startAngle: -90,  
      endAngle: 90,  
      center: ['50%', '70%'],
      size: "200%"
    }  
  },  
  series: [{type: 'pie',name: 'Value',innerSize: '70%',data: data}]  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts chart consists of several HTML elements. The `height` option is used for setting height style for a child of the HTML element you created as a chart container.

The solution to your problem can be setting different heights:

CSS:

```
#container {
    height: 200px;
    ...
}
```

JS:

```
chart: {
    height: 400
},

series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Value',
    innerSize: '70%',
    center: ['50%', '50%'],
    data: data
}]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/du60mrgp/